# Postgresql export insert statements with a column annotated JPA @Lob

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am facing an issue while exporting insert statements from postgresql database. Let me give you some information ;
Lets say I have a Foo class and a String field which is annotated with JPA **@Lob** annotation :

```
class Foo {
    @NotBlank
    @Lob
    @Column(length = 6000)
    private String content;
}
```

When I persist a new obj into database with a string content.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setContent('I have a problem with @Lob annotation.');
```

It looks like below :

```
id content
1  1234
```

No sign of content! It is a unique id of content which is stored somewhere in the database. It is okay no problem until this point. But now, I want to export this table insert statement and use in **another database.**

Exported sql is  :

```
INSERT INTO Foo (id,content) VALUES (5, '1234');
```

As you see if I execute this on another database , it thinks "1234" is a **string**, not unique id. Because it does not know anything about previous actions. 
So how is it possible to handle this situation ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `As you see if i execute this on another database` ... AFAIK if you run that `INSERT` statement on any database, the `1234` would be treated as a number, not a string.  For a string, it should be in single quotes.

Comment: `select pageno from pg_largeobject where loid = 5;` what gives you?..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is already a string. sorry for missing quotes.